# How to make Visual Studio Publish honor the "Copy if Newer" setting?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, publish, nlog

An ASP.NET (*not* Core) project.

Certain files, such as `NLog.config`, are set to `Copy if newer` (as per [NLog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#nlog-config-xml)).

And if I click Build this works: `NLog.config` is only copied to the build directory if it is newer than the version that already is in the build directory.

However, if I click Publish, then `NLog.config` is copied to the publish directory *no matter what*, overwriting the version that is already there. (I'm publishing to file system).

It would be really helpful if the version that already is in the publish directory took precedence.

Note that `NLog.config` is likely to contain settings that are *specific to the environment the app is published to* and *cannot* be set in the app's source code nor pushed to git.

There is an option to make Publish not delete files already present if it can't overwrite them with anything - so if I remove `NLog.config` from source code and only keep it in the publish (and build) directories, things will work as expected. However, I cannot do so: I was explicitly asked to make Publish place a default version of `NLog.config` that only logs to a file if there is no such version in the publish location yet.

Is there any remedy here? Is there any way to force Publish not to overwrite `NLog.config` if it already exists in target location or at least not overwrite it if it's newer?

Comment: based on my search, currently there is no options to limit Publish not to overwrite the Nlog.config. If you indeed, you could request a feature in the [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: Make sure NOT to use the nuget-package NLog.config - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config/ It will reset your NLog.config on deployment. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLog-Install

Comment: @RolfKristensen I'm not using it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try and fiddle with `CopyToPublishDirectory` that can have the values `Always, PreserveNewest, Never`:

```
<None Include="nlog.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```